# Statistics-Math-Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

An urn is filled with 10 green balls, 4 red balls, and 2 orange balls.  Three balls are selected without replacement.  Calculate the following probabilities:

(a) P(at least one ball is red)
I think the answer is: (4/16)(3/15)(2/14) = .007 or 1/140

(b) P(exactly one ball is orange)
I think the answer is: (2/16)(14/15)(13/14) + (14/16)(2/15)(13/14) + (14/16)(13/15)(2/14) = 13/40 or .325

(c) P(at most one ball is green)

(d) P(neither ball is red)

Comment: You will find that you will get more detailed answers if you show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a), I would calculate the probability that $no$ red ball is selected, and subtract the result from one.

For part (b), you are correct, but notice that your three terms are equal. Why is this? Try to find the pattern and generalize it.

For part (c), you can take the sum of $P$(exactly one ball is green), whose calculation mirrors that of part (b), plus $P$(no ball is green), whose calculation mirrors that of part (a).

For part (d), you just need to find P(no ball is red), which you should be able to recycle from part (a).

Comment: So D would be: (12/16)(11/15)(10/14)= 11/28 and A would be: 1-(11/28)=17/28?

Comment: I am still confused on where I went wrong on B...

Comment: Nothing went wrong in (b). I am simply noting that there is a pattern that you could find and use as a tool for future problems. Try to find an algebraic expression for the probability of drawing $exactly$ $k$ many balls of a certain color, on $n$ draws, supposing the frequency of of that color ball is $f \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

Total number of ways you can select 3 balls = ${16\choose3}$

Part a) $$=1-\frac{{12\choose3}}{{16\choose3}} = 0.6071$$

Part b)$$=\frac{{2\choose1}{14\choose2}}{{16\choose3}}=0.325$$

Part c) $$=\frac{{10\choose0}{6\choose3}+{10\choose1}{6\choose2}}{{16\choose3}}=0.3035$$

Part d) $$=\frac{{12\choose3}{4\choose0}}{{16\choose3}}=0.39285$$

Comment: Can I know why a downvote?